# SQL 2005: Optimize upsert-like Stored Procedure using Cursor, possible?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005, cursor, upsert

Ok So this is the second time i'm trying to fix this.

I was wondering if there is a possible way to optimize the cursor created for a stored procedure, used to iterate through a big select statement with two unions. In which later on, the stored procedure begins inserting values to a staging table checking each value against a "where not exist" select statement.

Or better yet, is it possible to create all this with a select statement and possibly joins.

The inserting process takes far too long to complete, and I would recon selecting the data would be much faster.

Here is an example of the SQL:

```
declare @ID1 varchar(40) ,
        @ID2 varchar(20) ,
        @State varchar(20) ,
        @isActive bit

Declare CuTable SCROLL INSENSITIVE cursor for
    Select 
        Cast(ID1 as Varchar(20)) AS ID1, 
        Cast(ID2 as Varchar(20)) AS ID2,  
        'AT' AS [State], 
        CASE When (isAvtiveDate > { fn CURDATE() }) or isAvtiveDate is null Then 1 else 0 end AS isAvtive
    From 
        server1.db.dbo.table1 
    Inner Join 
        server1.db.dbo.table2 on ID2 = ID1
    Where ID3 = 1 AND isActiveDate <= ISNULL(isActiveDate,'2020-01-01')

    UNION

    Select
        Cast(ID1 as Varchar(20)) AS ID1, 
        Cast(ID2 as Varchar(20)) AS ID2, 
        'AP' AS [State], 
        CASE When (isActiveDate > { fn CURDATE() }) or isActiveDate is null Then 1 else 0 end AS isActive
    From 
        server1.db.dbo.table1 
    Inner Join 
        server1.db.dbo.table2 on ID2 = ID1
    Where 
        ID3 = 2 AND isActiveDate <= ISNULL(isActiveDate,'2020-01-01')
UNION
Select
           Cast(ID1 as Varchar(20)) AS ID1, 
           Cast(ID2 as Varchar(20)) AS ID2,
           'AH' AS [State], 
           CASE When (isActiveDate > { fn CURDATE() }) or isActiveDate is null Then 1 else 0 end AS isActive
From server1.db.dbo.table1 inner join server1.db.dbo.table2 on ID2 = ID1
           inner join server1.db.dbo.table13 on ID2 = ID4
Where ID3 = 5 and toDate is null and fromDate is not null AND isActiveDate <= ISNULL(isActiveDate,'2020-01-01')


Open CuTable
Fetch Next From CuTable Into  @ID1, @ID2, @[State], @isActive

While @@Fetch_Status = 0

Begin
    Insert Into StagingTable (ID1, ID2, [State], isActive) 

           --Values 
           Select @ID1, @ID2, @[State], @isActive
           where not exists(select * from StagingTable  where ID1 = @ID1 and ID2 = @ID2)


Fetch Next From CuTable Into @ID1, @ID2, @[State], @isActive

End

close CuTable
deallocate CuTable
```

HEADS UP: I'm using SQL SERVER 2005

### UPDATE regarding Leonidas199x comment thread:

[image: duplicate records]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think you need a cursor at all, as the data is not dynamically changing. You should be able to do this with a set based approach. Below is an example using CTE, with a left join to only insert those that do not exist in the staging table:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT      CAST(ID1 as Varchar(20)) AS ID1, 
            CAST(ID2 as Varchar(20)) AS ID2,  
            'AT' AS [State], 
            CASE When (isAvtiveDate > { fn CURDATE() }) or isAvtiveDate is null Then 1 else 0 end AS isAvtive
FROM        server1.db.dbo.table1 
INNER JOIN  server1.db.dbo.table2 on ID2 = ID1
WHERE       ID3 = 1 AND isActiveDate <= ISNULL(isActiveDate,'2020-01-01')

UNION

SELECT      CAST(ID1 as Varchar(20)) AS ID1, 
            CAST(ID2 as Varchar(20)) AS ID2, 
            'AP' AS [State], 
            CASE WHEN (isActiveDate > { fn CURDATE() }) or isActiveDate is null Then 1 else 0 end AS isActive
FROM        server1.db.dbo.table1 
INNER JOIN  server1.db.dbo.table2 on ID2 = ID1
WHERE       ID3 = 2 AND isActiveDate <= ISNULL(isActiveDate,'2020-01-01')

UNION

SELECT
            Cast(ID1 as Varchar(20)) AS ID1, 
            Cast(ID2 as Varchar(20)) AS ID2,
            'AH' AS [State], 
            CASE When (isActiveDate > { fn CURDATE() }) or isActiveDate is null Then 1 else 0 end AS isActive
FROM        server1.db.dbo.table1 
INNER JOIN  server1.db.dbo.table2   ON ID2 = ID1
INNER JOIN  server1.db.dbo.table13  ON ID2 = ID4
WHERE       ID3 = 5 and toDate is null and fromDate is not null AND isActiveDate <= ISNULL(isActiveDate,'2020-01-01')
)
INSERT INTO StagingTable 
        (
            ID1, 
            ID2, 
            [State], 
            isActive
        ) 
SELECT      DISTINCT 
            CT.ID1, 
            CT.ID2, 
            CT.[State], 
            CT.isActive
FROM        CTE             AS  CT
LEFT JOIN   StagingTable    AS  ST  ON  ST.ID1 = CT.ID1 AND ST.ID2 = CT.ID2
WHERE       ST.ID1 IS NULL 
AND         ST.ID2 IS NULL;
```

Given the requirement to check each row as the cursor does, I would use the following, using a temp table to check each set of ID1 and ID2 that are identified are unique when inserting into the temp table, then do the insert to the staging table from the temp table:

```
/*Create temp table*/
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpData') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpData
GO
CREATE TABLE #tmpData
        (
            ID1             VARCHAR(20) ,
            ID2             VARCHAR(20) ,
            [State]         VARCHAR(2)  ,
            IsActiveData    BIT
        )

/*Insert into the temp table, with each insert join back to the temp table to ensure ID1 and ID2 are not already inserted*/
INSERT INTO #tmpData
        (
            ID1                     ,
            ID2                     ,
            [State]                 ,
            IsActiveData
        )
SELECT      CAST(ID1 as Varchar(20))    AS ID1, 
            CAST(ID2 as Varchar(20))    AS ID2,  
            'AT'                        AS [State], 
            CASE WHEN (isAvtiveDate > { fn CURDATE() }) or isAvtiveDate is null Then 1 else 0 end AS isAvtive
FROM        server1.db.dbo.table1 
INNER JOIN  server1.db.dbo.table2 on ID2 = ID1
WHERE       ID3 = 1 AND isActiveDate <= ISNULL(isActiveDate,'2020-01-01')

INSERT INTO #tmpData
        (
            ID1                     ,
            ID2                     ,
            [State]                 ,
            IsActiveData
        )
SELECT      CAST(T1.ID1 as VARCHAR(20)) AS ID1, 
            CAST(T2.ID2 as VARCHAR(20)) AS ID2, 
            'AP'                        AS [State], 
            CASE WHEN (isActiveDate > { fn CURDATE() }) or isActiveDate is null Then 1 else 0 end AS isActive
FROM        server1.db.dbo.table1       AS  T1
INNER JOIN  server1.db.dbo.table2       AS  T2  ON T2.ID2 = T1.ID1
LEFT JOIN   #tmpData                    AS  T   ON  T.ID1 = T1.ID1 AND T.ID2 = T2.ID2
WHERE       ID3 = 2 AND isActiveDate <= ISNULL(isActiveDate,'2020-01-01')
AND         T.ID1 IS NULL
AND         T.ID2 IS NULL

INSERT INTO #tmpData
        (
            ID1                     ,
            ID2                     ,
            [State]                 ,
            IsActiveData
        )
SELECT
            Cast(T1.ID1 as Varchar(20)) AS ID1, 
            Cast(T2.ID2 as Varchar(20)) AS ID2,
            'AH' AS [State], 
            CASE When (isActiveDate > { fn CURDATE() }) OR isActiveDate IS NULL Then 1 else 0 end AS isActive
FROM        server1.db.dbo.table1       AS  T1
INNER JOIN  server1.db.dbo.table2       AS  T2  ON  T2.ID2  = T1.ID1
INNER JOIN  server1.db.dbo.table13      AS  T13 ON  T2.ID2  = T13.ID4
LEFT JOIN   #tmpData                    AS  T   ON  T.ID1   = T1.ID1 AND T.ID2 = T2.ID2
WHERE       ID3             =   5 
AND         toDate          IS NULL 
AND         fromDate        IS NOT NULL 
AND         isActiveDate    <= ISNULL(isActiveDate,'2020-01-01')
AND         T.ID1           IS NULL
AND         T.ID2           IS NULL




/*Insert into the staging table from the temp table ensuring only records that are not already in there are inserted.*/
INSERT INTO StagingTable 
        (
            ID1, 
            ID2, 
            [State], 
            isActive
        ) 
SELECT      CT.ID1, 
            CT.ID2, 
            CT.[State], 
            CT.isActive
FROM        #tmpData        AS  CT
LEFT JOIN   StagingTable    AS  ST  ON  ST.ID1 = CT.ID1 AND ST.ID2 = CT.ID2
WHERE       ST.ID1 IS NULL 
AND         ST.ID2 IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, i will definitely check this out. :)

Comment: Well It worked in copying the data to the staging table but it didn't have the same effect as the Stored Procedure with the cursor. 

I know there is an "ID1" in the bigger Select statements with the unions that is '3098'. When i do a select in the original result after running the Stored Procedure with the cursor i only get one record with the ID1 = '3098'.

With your method i get both records, that is two of the same record having ID1 ='3098'.

Also the result of all rows is about 71511 rows, it should be 71510 rows.  @Leonidas199x

Comment: I see, that makes sense as the cursor will check each time, so is exposed to what has been inserted before it. Should be solved by placing DISTINCT on the select query for the insert (updated answer), so long as the data is the same, of course.

Comment: I'm really confused. Just saw the update you made to your query, tried the distinct exactly where you put it i still get 71511 records, that duplicate doesn't get excluded. For some reason all the columns are in varchar, can that have something to do with why the comparing functionality doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Shouldn't do. Ideally need to see the data. The UNION would remove none unique records, so I presume that the dupe is coming from the same SELECT statement. Are the records exactly the same?

Comment: Just updated the fist post with the two records. I know the Stored Procedure with the cursor checks if two values (ID1 and ID2) match in the same row.

Comment: Shouldn't a Upsert be something to consider, that is if the record already exists the update or something?  @Leonidas199x

Comment: The record that is kept and inserted seems to be the last one "3098 | 15086 | AT | 0" which makes me think it updates the row that first got inserted "3098 | 15086 | AP | 0".

So thats why i think the distinct doesn't work in this case, in the original Stored Procedure up-top it distinctly compares ID1 and ID2 with "@ID1" and "@ID2", when we do a distinct we don't do it specifically to just those two id's we do it on the whole row, which in turn results in the duplicates because the column '[state]' in that row differ. How do i solve that problem?

Comment: @John that is exactly the problem with using the distinct. I have updated my answer with a separate solution. You may need to check aliasing etc.

Comment: I cant manage to get it to work, allot of errors occurring. multiple 'Ambiguous column name' occurring

Comment: @John as I mentioned, you would need to sort the aliasing, specifically anything I haven't aliased as I didn't know which table it has come from.

Comment: Yeah still tinkering haha :P

Comment: Ok, so i managed to get the whole code to work, it removes that duplicate but still adds 8 more records from somewhere. Any idea on what can be causing that?

Comment: Not without seeing the data I am afraid. Sure it is an easy fix, but without knowing what is added, it is hard to say why.

Comment: In data, do you mean the results or also the complete tables that are joined?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157017/discussion-between-leonidas199x-and-john).

Comment: Just Posted results in the chat :)

Comment: I think i managed to fix the problem, i had to put "distinct" on both the first select statements that gets added to the #tmpdata table.

Comment: Yeah, Thank you so much for your help and insight though, it was much appreciated and helped out a lot :)